# Combine census tracts with neighbor to reach a population threshold in R

Tags: r, iteration, spatial, shapefile, nearest-neighbor

I need to combine small geographic units (census tracts) with their neighbor with the smallest population in an iterative fashion until a population threshold (ex: >=200) is reached and the values for the combined units are summed (added).

The ultimate goal is to run an analysis of spatial autocorrelation but some units have such a small population that they should be combined with a neighbor (such as a merge in [GIS](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/merge-features-into-one-feature.htm) that adds some of the values for the two features together). I also have some geographic units that are "islands" so have no neighbors. I'm working in R because I need code that can be re-used for multiple calculations but am also familiar with QGIS and Geoda so for "islands" with no neighbors I can manually alter the neighbors matrix to eliminate islands if needed but it would be better if instead I could write code to search for the nearest neighbor.

See sample data below of census tracts in Richmond County, NY (Staten Island) which has 7 tracts below a threshold of 200. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
library(tidycensus)
richmondtracts <- get_decennial(
  geography = "tract",
  state = "NY",
  county = "Richmond",
  variables = c(
    Hispanic = "P2_002N" #Hispanic population per tract
  ),
  summary_var = "P2_001N", #total population per tract
  year = 2020,
  geometry = TRUE
)
```

As a fairly new coder, I've been playing around with ChatGPT which has made some suggestions using while loops but they don't run. I'm a bit stuck but found this forum where geographic units are merged with a neighbor based on area: [Merging small polygons with largest neighbour in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989088/merging-small-polygons-with-largest-neighbour-in-r)

Comment: Hi Busybee03, welcome to SO. Just have a couple of questions before I can help: 1) How do you want to handle the attributes of the merge? Specifically, does it matter which GEOID/NAME value is kept after a merge? 2) For your non-contiguous census tracts, do you want the geometry retained e.g. create a multipart feature? Or do you want drop the "island" geometry and just add the census counts to its nearest neighbour?

Comment: 3) How do you want to prioritise the merges? For instance, the tracts 36085022801, 36085022802, and 36085022602 are large relative to the rest of the tracts. So do you want to restrict merges in a way that minimises the size of any potential merges? In other words, do you need to keep the data as spatially representative as possible, or can any tract < 200 merge with any other tract? This bit is important to consider regarding analysis such as spatial autocorrelation, GWC etc.

Comment: Also, based on your code I'm getting 10 tracts with an Hispanic population < 200 (and 1 with empty geometry). Are you only interested in 7 of these, or is it a typo in your question? And in my previous questions when I say size, I'm referring to area rather than population.

Comment: @LTyrone Thanks so much for your questions and help! I don't think it matters which GEOID / name is kept since I can always use a spatial join to regain this information. Good point about the size of the tracts. The idea was to use queen neighbors to create a spatial neighbors weight matrix for a LISA analysis and the thought was to prioritize the merge with the tract with the lowest population total.

Comment: I realized I addressed 1 & 3 in the first comment. 2. For noncontiguous tracts, I think a multipart feature should be created? In reality any island does have something it connects to (usually the nearest feature via a bridge, etc). 4. Yes you're correct, I was using the 2010 tract data for my actual file but yes the 2020 geography I used in the example code does give 7 tracts with population <200 plus the 1 with empty geometry which I think could be excluded. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Great stuff! I'll have a look at it once I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR***

It may be better to manually do the merges.

***Preamble***

The following answer works in limited situations. That’s because, depending on the range and spatial distribution of values for a given ethnicity, there may be an ‘unrealistic’ number of permutations to account for in order to automate your desired outcome. To find a merge match for all tracts < the threshold in all situations requires an algorithm more complex than the one outlined below. This stands even if restricting merges to the neighbouring tract with the lowest value.

I suggest examining the values of all ethnic groups at the same time to see if there are below threshold tracts that could be permanently merged. If that is not possible, a suggested workflow would be to first plot the tracts < the threshold and defining merge matches by ‘eyeballing’ the data and assigning merge ids manually. Then, pivot the data based on merge ids and use `summarise()` to merge the tracts. In essence, this is the foundation of the following answer.

This method has only been tested on the outlined example data and is likely to fail in certain situations not limited to:

- tracts that require > two degrees of tract separation in order to meet or exceed value threshold
- where two tracts (x and y) match to the same neighbour (z) and the ‘tie breaker’ border length of xz and yz are identical. Although the likelihood of this happening is very low, it is not zero

This method considers tracts with value == 0 as needing to be merged. Doing so tends to exacerbate the ecologically fallacious nature of census tract data. You will need to check how to manage this regarding your chosen analysis methods e.g. whether is it ok to include tracts with value == 0.

For simplicity, neighbours that only share a single node/vertex are ignored. Also, there are no non-contiguous tracts in your example data so this answer includes a version of richmondtracts with two tracts identified as islands.

The criteria of lowest value neighbour may not be the best approach given [Tobler’s First Law](https://gisgeography.com/tobler-first-law-of-geography/). For instance, in the modified example data, the polygon with oid == 33 is matched with 32 and 29. Because 29 is further away than 55, it would arguably be more methodically sound to match 33 based on proximity.

Some steps will return warnings. They can be safely ignored for the purposes of this answer. The “although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar” warning is telling you `st_intersection()` processes data as if were PCS and your data are defined by a GCS. For this solution, the returned results are fine. The “repeating attributes for all sub-geometries for which they may not be constant” warning is telling you that variables such as value and summary_value get repeated if for instance a MULTIPOLYGON gets split into two or more POLYGON features. In other words, do not sum value and/or summary_value if you join them back together.

***Workflow***

0. Add oid column to data as a key field for subsequent merges
1. Create LINESTRING version of tract data to determine length of neighbour borders. In the event two or more tracts match to the same lowest value neighbour, length is used as a ‘tie break’
2. Check for non-contiguous tracts (islands). If false, skip to step 6. If islands exist, create copies of tract data, one with only island and one with only contiguous.
3. Find nearest neighbour of islands, assign each match a unique merge_id, and output to dataframe
4. Join dataframe from previous step to tract data and output new df with merged polygons. No more islands
5. Recreate LINESTRING version of new df tract data
6. Create LINESTRING versions of polygons with value < threshold
7. Find LINESTRINGs of neighbouring polygons, `summarise()` by neighbour oid, and calculate border length. Create columns to determine whether a neighbour can be considered for merging:

- threshold: check the sum of the neighbours and below threshold tract enough to exceed threshold
- dupe_match: return count of how many matches a neighbour has
- dupe_rank: rank duplicates matches based on length
- candidates: check if at least one neighbour can sum to reach threshold
- `filter()` rows: if they do not sum to >= threshold *only if* there are other candidates; if duplicate matches do not have the longest border; and then return the match with minimum value *only if* a neighbour match exists
- if no matches available, return neighbour’s neighbours and match to lowest neighbour’s neighbours value
- `arrange()` so `slice_head()` returns lowest available value match
- assign unique merge ids, pivot to long form, and use `summarise()` to merge matched tracts

```
library(tidycensus)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lwgeom)
library(ggplot2)

# Original data
richmondtracts <- get_decennial(
  geography = "tract",
  state = "NY",
  county = "Richmond",
  variables = c(
    Hispanic = "P2_002N" #Hispanic population per tract
  ),
  summary_var = "P2_001N", #total population per tract
  year = 2020,
  geometry = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!st_is_empty(.)) %>% # Remove empty geometries
  mutate(oid = 1:n()) # Add rownames as integer, oid is basis for defining merges

### Modifications for illustrative purposes, skip to step 1 if using original data
# Modify richmondtracts to demonstrate permutations of islands and no neighbours > threshold
richmondtracts <- richmondtracts %>%
  st_cast(., "POLYGON") %>%
  mutate(oid = 1:n())

richmondtracts[95, c(1,2,4,5)] <- list("30000000000",
                          "Census Tract 000, Richmond County, New York",
                          1, 5)

richmondtracts[c(9,32,60),"value"] <- c(1,2,3)
###

# 1. Generate geometries for determining length of neighbouring polygon borders (for tie break)
# Generate POINT version of polygon data
p <- richmondtracts %>%
  st_cast(., "POLYGON") %>%
  st_cast(., "POINT") %>%
  st_intersection()

# Generate LINESTRING version of polygon data
l <- richmondtracts %>%
  st_cast(., "POLYGON") %>%
  st_cast(., "LINESTRING")

# Split LINESTRING version to individual lines
spl <- st_split(l, p) %>%
  st_collection_extract(., "LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(row.id = 1:n())

# 2. Merge islands to nearest nonisland
# Get oid of all islands
islands <- data.frame(st_intersects(richmondtracts)) %>%
  group_by(col.id) %>%
  filter(n() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ### NOTE: Only for modified example data, skip this line if using original data
  add_row(row.id = 35, col.id = 35)

if(nrow(islands) == 0) {
  
  df <- richmondtracts
  print("No non-contiguous tracts found, skip to step 6")
  print("Optionally run step 4a for a pre-merge comparison plot")
  
} else {
  
  print("Non-contiguous tracts found, continue on from here")
  
}

# If islands exist
islands <- richmondtracts %>%
  filter(oid %in% islands[["row.id"]])

# Get all non-islands
nonisland <- richmondtracts %>%
  filter(!oid %in% islands[["oid"]])

# 3. Find polygons in nonislands nearest to each island and assign each 'match' a unique merge_id
islands <- islands %>%
  mutate(nearest = st_nearest_feature(islands, nonisland)) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  group_by(oid) %>%
  mutate(merge_id = cur_group_id() + nrow(richmondtracts)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(oid, nearest, merge_id) %>%
  pivot_longer(-merge_id,
               values_to = "oid") %>%
  select(oid, merge_id)

# 4. Create new version of richmondtracts with islands merged to nearest nonislands
df <- richmondtracts %>%
  left_join(., islands, by = "oid") %>%
  mutate(merge_id = ifelse(is.na(merge_id), oid, merge_id)) %>%
  group_by(merge_id) %>%
  summarise(GEOID = first(GEOID),
            oid = first(oid),
            value = sum(value),
            summary_value = sum(summary_value),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
  ungroup()

# 4a. Return polygons with values below threshold (for plot)
polysub <- richmondtracts %>%
  filter(as.numeric(unlist(value)) < 200) %>%
  mutate(row.id = as.integer(rownames(.)))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = richmondtracts,
          colour = "blue",
          fill = "grey90",
          lwd = .5,
          linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_sf(data = polysub,
          fill = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = df,
          color = "grey70",
          fill = NA,
          lwd = .5) +
  geom_sf_text(data = filter(df, !oid %in% polysub[["oid"]]),
               aes(label = oid),
               size = 1,
               fun.geometry = st_centroid,
               show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_sf_text(data = polysub,
               aes(label = oid),
               size = 2,
               fun.geometry = st_centroid,
               show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#e3eeff", colour = "#e3eeff"),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))

# 5. Merge tracts to ensure no polygon value < given threshold (e.g. 200)
# Regenerate geometries for determining length of polygon borders based on updated tracts.
p <- df %>%
  st_cast(., "POLYGON") %>%
  st_cast(., "POINT") %>%
  st_intersection()

l <- df %>%
  st_cast(., "POLYGON") %>%
  st_cast(., "LINESTRING")

spl <- st_split(l, p) %>%
  st_collection_extract(., "LINESTRING") %>%
  mutate(row.id = 1:n())

# 6. Return polygons with values below threshold
polysub <- df %>%
  filter(as.numeric(unlist(value)) < 200) %>%
  mutate(row.id = as.integer(rownames(.)))

# Return LINESTRING version of polysub
linesub <- spl %>%
  filter(.[["oid"]] %in% polysub[["oid"]]) %>%
  mutate(row.id = 1:n())

# 7. Create new version of df with polygons < threshold merged to neighbour with lowest value
df1 <- linesub %>%
  st_equals(., spl) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  left_join(., select(data.frame(linesub), oid, row.id, value, summary_value),
            by = join_by(row.id)) %>%
  left_join(., spl, by = join_by(col.id == row.id),
            relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  select(-col.id) %>%
  filter(!oid.x == oid.y) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  group_by(oid.x, oid.y)  %>%
  summarise(value = min(value.x),
            value1 = min(value.y),
            summary_value = min(summary_value.x),
            summary_value1 = min(summary_value.y),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(length_m = st_length(.)) %>%
  filter(!oid.x == oid.y) %>%
  group_by(oid.y) %>%
  mutate(threshold = ifelse((value + value1) >= 200, 1, 0),
         dupe_match = n(),
         dupe_rank = rank(length_m)) %>%
  group_by(oid.x) %>%
  mutate(candidates = any(sum(threshold) > 0)) %>%
  filter(!threshold == 0 & candidates == TRUE | candidates == FALSE) %>%
  filter(!dupe_rank < dupe_match & candidates == TRUE | candidates == FALSE) %>%
  filter(value1 == min(value1) | candidates == FALSE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(candidates == FALSE,
                         value1[match(oid.y, oid.x)],
                         value1),
         oid.y = ifelse(candidates == FALSE,
                        oid.y[match(oid.y, oid.x)],
                        oid.y)) %>%
  group_by(oid.x) %>%
  arrange(oid.x, value1) %>%
  slice_head() %>%
  mutate(value1 = ifelse(candidates == FALSE, 0, value1)) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  group_by(oid.y) %>%
  mutate(merge_id = cur_group_id() + nrow(richmondtracts)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(oid.x, oid.y, merge_id) %>%
  pivot_longer(-merge_id,
               values_to = "oid") %>%
  select(oid, merge_id) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  left_join(if("merge_id" %in% names(df)) { select(df, -merge_id) } else { df }, .,
            by = "oid") %>%
  mutate(merge_id = ifelse(is.na(merge_id), oid, merge_id)) %>%
  group_by(merge_id) %>%
  summarise(GEOID = first(GEOID),
            oid = first(oid),
            value = sum(value),
            summary_value = sum(summary_value),
            .groups = "drop") %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df1,
          color = NA,
          fill = "grey90",
          lwd = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = filter(df1, merge_id > nrow(richmondtracts)),
          aes(fill = factor(oid)),
          lwd = .5,
          show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_sf(data = df1,
          color = "grey70",
          fill = NA,
          lwd = .5) +
  geom_sf(data = polysub,
          color = "blue",
          fill = NA,
          lwd = .75,
          linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_sf(data = richmondtracts,
          color = "grey40",
          fill = NA,
          lwd = .4,
          linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_sf_text(data = filter(df1, merge_id > nrow(richmondtracts)),
               aes(label = oid),
               size = 2,
               fun.geometry = st_centroid,
               show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_sf_text(data = df,
               aes(label = oid),
               size = 1,
               fun.geometry = st_centroid,
               show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#e3eeff", colour = "#e3eeff"),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))
```

Modified example data result pre and post merge:

[image: mod data]

Original data result pre and post merge:

[image: original data]

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @LTyrone works well for most cases but for more complex admin areas it is very slow.

I tried for admin 1 area of Bahamas and it did not finish it within couple of hours. To solve this, the 1. step can be made much quicker with terra-package's `disagg()` function, as follows:

```
# 1. step:
# load terra package
library(terra)

# Convert the sf object to a terra object
v_richmondtracts <- vect(richmondtracts)

# split polygons to individual lines
v_spl <-disagg(v_richmondtracts, segments = T)
# back to simple feature and add row.id
spl <- st_as_sf(v_spl) %>%
    mutate(row.id = 1:n())
```

Doing the Bahamas, for example, in couple of seconds. And then continue with the original solutions.

Other problem I faced was that in some cases an area can be a 'target' and 'source' for merge, resulting duplicates to the merged dataset. For a quick solution, I added one line for step 7. just before last group_by:

```
# new line    
distinct(oid, .keep_all = T) %>% 
# old code continues
group_by(merge_id) %>%
#...
```

And then just run the code for few rounds if areas with less than threshold population still exist.